# My newly deployed Website working with mobile data but not on wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, internet, godaddy, digital-ocean

I deployed my django website today on digital ocean. I can access it by its droplet's IP address. Then I configured domain name. Everything is fine and I can access my website from Mobile by domain name. 
But on wifi when I enter domain Godaddy parking page stating site coming soon comes. I can access it by IP but not by domain on wifi network. Even my ssl also don't work on then. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you check your site on here: https://www.whatsmydns.net/?

Comment: It is green tick everywhere except in India. I need it here. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

## What's the problem

You need to wait for the DNS records to propogate.

## How long will this take

It'll normally be done in under 48 hours

As you said the propagation checker said the record was wrong, you'll need to wait

## Workarounds

Using the hosts file you can specify fixed IPs for host names,  or you can override your DNS server to use one that has already propagated.

Comment: it is already more than 48 hr.

Comment: I have created a chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78854/discussion-of-my-newly-deployed-website-working-with-mobile-data-but-not-on-wifi