# Websites on VPS accessible on mobile data but not on school network (don't think it's DNS)

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, vps, apache2, domain-name

#### The problem

I am currently managing two websites on my VPS. I am using the [LAMP stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) (Apache web server), with Virtual Hosts configured for both websites. One of those two websites uses SSL.

I did all the configuration over the SSH, at home on my home WiFi and the server IP was accessible, same on 3G/4G using my phone hotspot.

The problem is, when I connect to my school WiFi ([Eduroam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam)), I can't:

- connect to the server using SSH (neither by *root@server_ip* nor *root@domain_name*)
- can't display the websites using browser (again, I tried server's IP or the domain names)
- can't get any response when ping-ing the server
- can't display any data when typing the server's IP directly to the browser

#### What I tried

As some people recommended it could be a problem with DNS (see more: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/916389/my-newly-deployed-website-working-with-mobile-data-but-not-on-wifi), [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/website-down-but-only-on-specific-wifi-networks)), I ran the `nslookup` command on my Ubuntu, using the Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8) and three others, all with the same result:

```
➜  ~ nslookup mywebsite.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mywebsite.com
Address: <the IP of my server was listed here>
```

The A records are set for both domain names and point to my VPS. Both domains have redirect from *www* to *non-www*. It's been more than several days since I edited the DNS records.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Contact the IT support for the campus you are on. It sounds like they have blocked your IP address.